# Why does a React parent component exhibit different states when an update function is called from multiple child components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React parent component managing a state called `placedMarkers` using `useState`. This state is passed down to several child components (Marker components), each receiving a function named `updatePlacedMarkers` as a prop. The `updatePlacedMarkers` function updates the state and logs its content.

Problem:
When I call the `updatePlacedMarkers` function from different intances of the child component, the state seems to be different depending on which child component the function is called from. If the function is triggered from the first instance it only shows one entry. If it's triggered from the second instance it shows 2 entries etc... Why could this be happening?

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
// In the parent component
const [placedMarkers, setPlacedMarkers] = useState([]);

  const updatePlacedMarkers = (markerProps, newPosition) => {
    console.log("placedmarker", placedMarkers);
  };

{placedMarkers.map((marker) => (
  <Marker
    key={marker.id}
    position={marker.position}
    id={marker.id}
    icon={marker.icon}
    label={marker.label}
    draggable={true}
    optimized={false}
    placedMarkers={placedMarkers}
    updatePlacedMarkers={updatePlacedMarkers}
  />
))}
```

I have already checked that the marker IDs are unique, and the `updatePlacedMarkers` function correctly updates the state. Are there any other aspects or best practices that I might have overlooked that could lead to this behavior?

I was expecting to get the actual current state of placedMarkers.

If i trigger that function from a button it shows the actual value of placedMarkers.

Comment: The symptoms make me think there's a stale version of the function being used. Can you show us the `Marker` component and what it does with `updatePlacedMarkers`?

Comment: Such an issue might occur if you are mutating state. How are you updating the parent state? Are you perhaps doing something like `placedMarkers.push(something)` followed by `updateMarkers(placedMarkers)`?

Comment: One mistake could be in thinking that logging the stated value immediately after a state update means that it's actually finished running the react lifecycle and has finished internal updates. If you move your logging to a useEffect with the stated value in the dependency array then you'll know for sure as this will log as a side effect/consequence of the state update having finished. The code snippet you've provided doesn't include any state updates so it's hard to know for sure - maybe updating that will help you get an answer too.